# How to use C# to send data to Arduino board

Tags: c#, arduino

I have an Arduino Uno board, I succeeded in sending a .txt file to it using Java with Processing 2 software, I want to know how to do this using C#.

Comment: StackOverflow is there to solve specific programming problems, not to act as a tutorial or teacher. If you want to know how to do it, look on Google. Once you face a specific problem, come back here with the code.

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can add in a `SerialPort` and use `Serial.Writeline("Hello");` to send those to the arduino. On your arduino code simply use `Serial.Read` to read the data.

You may find this useful too:

Visual Basic Serial COM Port Tutorial (Visual Studio 2010) - Part 1
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=krN6pWm6s6o